# How to have menu out from iframe and show over two iframes?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have tow iFrame if1 and if2. if1 has Menu, menu height is 100%. and if1 height is 10%. if2 has 90% height. if1 and if2 are in horizontal positions. When I clicked on menu from if1 it shows only 10% view and remaining part of menu goes back to if2. How can i bring menu above both iframes. 
Is there any other way to solve this problem?

```
<div id="xwikimaincontainer" >
<iframe src="https://localhost/headerFile" width="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" height="200px" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen wmode="transparent"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="xwikimaincontainerinner"> Here main contaent comes</div>
```

In this code xwikimaincontainer div has header file src of one application  and has menu. xwikimaincontainerinner div has xwiki application.

Comment: please provide some code or even a fille - jsfiddle.net

Comment: @messerbill this code i wrote in xwiki vm templete.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, content cannot break out of an iframe for many reasons, security not the least.